# I want to place Table View exact down to navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, autolayout

[image]

Please see the dashed-box area, this is extra space appearing between navigation bar & table view.

I've tried 3 things but same problem.
1. Cleared all constrains & "Add missing constrains"
2. I've used pin, & keep '0' distance to UI object above table view
3. I've used dragging method, & set vertical spacing for table view.

Comment: Is that a header view? Or the background of the superView of the `UITableView` Or is its height equals to the height of the UINavigationBar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You nee to uncheck the property inside `attribute inspector` `Adjust Scroll View Insets` using `storyboard` see image below.

[image]

**Edit:**

**Adjust Scroll View Insets**: Defines a Boolean value that indicates whether the view controller should automatically adjust its scroll view insets.

The default value of this property is true, which lets container view controllers know that they should adjust the scroll view insets of this view controller’s view to account for screen areas consumed by a status bar, search bar, navigation bar, toolbar, or tab bar. Set this property to false if your view controller implementation manages its own scroll view inset adjustments.

Comment: thanks, can you please extend your answer with some explanations, so that, in future it'll help other as well. Why, what was the problem, why we need to do this. etc

Answer (score 2):

Select *View Controller* and Check *Adjust scroll View insets*.

[image: Adjust scroll View insets]

Comment: I think you want to say, uncheck?

Comment: Un checking worked? What is your table's top constraint?

Comment: Can you show your storyboard with tableview selected and constraints shown?

Comment: Okay, I got it, you wanted to add the table view just below the Navigation Bar. BTW, we can also attach top of the Table to the top of the ViewController and check adjust scroll view. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I've done it, I was placing table view under navigation bar, now I've placed it exactly touching upper bounds of the view. And added missing constrains. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVfJT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use this line in your tableview class's viewDidLoad method,

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

This sets the content from top.

It will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad:animated];
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By adding following line in **viewDidLoad** will solve this issue

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
```