# Why does the UINavigationBar cut off part of my UIBuilder but not cut it off when tested?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface

[image]

As you can see in the image (in the UIBuilder), the UINavigationBar takes up probably 60px of space at the top, but that does NOT show up in the simulator. The image you see above it how I have to put those view in order for them to be as far from the top of the status bar as they are from the sides. How can I fix this?

Comment: @J Doe [see this link may solve your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39590959/4003548).

Comment: @vaibhav This DID WORK, thank you!!!

Comment: welcome, can you please upvote that ans :)

Comment: Done. Is there anyway I can mark it as the solution? I made a solution just in case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I want to place Table View exact down to navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590834/i-want-to-place-table-view-exact-down-to-navigation-bar)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by user vaibhav, [this fixed the issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590834/i-want-to-place-table-view-exact-down-to-navigation-bar/39590959#39590959)

You need to click on your main view, go to attribute inspector, and un-click 'Adjust Scroll View Insets'. That is all. Thanks for the help!

Comment: actually i didn't got your upvote to that [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39590959/4003548) you upvoted my comment instead of answer  :)