# SearchBar does not stay in place (table headerview) - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have made a searchbar in my table header view. I actually would not mind having it in my navigation bar, by setting it to: `navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar`.. The problem is though that when the searchBar is active, the navigation bar is dismissed - including the searchBar, So you cannot see what you are searching for?

How can I change that? Here is my complete searchBar code:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FirebaseStorage

class SearchTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {


    @IBOutlet var searchUsersTableView: UITableView!


    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    var usersArray = [NSDictionary?]()
    var filteredUsers = [NSDictionary?]()

    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        //tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Søg"
        searchController.searchBar.setValue("Annuller", forKey:"_cancelButtonText")
        let cancelButtonAttributes: NSDictionary = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(cancelButtonAttributes as? [String : AnyObject], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        databaseRef.child("UserInformation").queryOrderedByChild("userName").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

            self.usersArray.append(snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)


            self.searchUsersTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: self.usersArray.count-1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)


            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


    }


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {

            let userId = user.uid

                     FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child(userId).child("NotificationBadge").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

                // Get user value
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let badgesNumber = value?["numberOfBadges"] as! Int?



                if badgesNumber != nil {

                    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3].badgeValue = String(badgesNumber!)

                } else {

                    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3].badgeValue = nil
                }

                // ...
            }) { (error) in
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        }

    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    }


    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showProfile" {
            if let nextVC = segue.destinationViewController as? theProfileTableViewController {
                nextVC.viaSegue = sender! as! String

            }
        }

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

        if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            return filteredUsers.count
        }
        return usersArray.count
    }




    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:SearchTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("searchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SearchTableViewCell



        let user: NSDictionary?

        if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
            user = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            user = self.usersArray[indexPath.row]
        }

        cell.nameLabel.text = user?["userName"] as? String

        let profileUserIDPic = user?["usersUID"] as? String

        let storage = FIRStorage.storage()

        // Refer to your own Firebase storage
        let storageRef = storage.referenceForURL("gs://bigr-1d864.appspot.com")

        let profilePicRef = storageRef.child(profileUserIDPic!+"/profile_pic.jpg")

        // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
        profilePicRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 300 * 300) { (data, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                print("Unable to download image")
                cell.profilePic.image = UIImage(named: "profile.png")
                cell.profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profilePic.frame.size.width/2
                cell.profilePic.clipsToBounds = true
            } else {
                // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
                // ... let islandImage: UIImage! = UIImage(data: data!)
                if (data != nil){
                    cell.profilePic.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    cell.profilePic.layer.cornerRadius = cell.profilePic.frame.size.width/2
                    cell.profilePic.clipsToBounds = true

                }
            }
        }




        return cell
    }


    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        // update something
        filterContent(self.searchController.searchBar.text!)

    }

    func filterContent(searchText: String) {
        self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter{ user in
            let username = user!["userName"] as? String

            return (username?.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString))!
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


}
```

**When going to the search page it looks like this (because I added the insets**
[image]

**When searching for a user it looks like this**
[image]

**When having click a user and returned to search it looks like this**
[image]

Comment: where do you want the search bar in header or navigation ???

Comment: In the navigation :-)

Comment: try `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false`

Comment: Worked like a charm! thanks :-)

Comment: When I search for a user and be very specific, so only one user shows - the tableview is behind the navigation bar, so the user is not showing unless you pull the tableview down? How can I fix this? @Joe

Comment: you can have a outlet of TOP constraint of Tableview and set it according to your need.

Comment: @Joe it is not a viewcontroller containing a tableview - it is a UITableViewController :)

Comment: sorry my bad. try this select your `tableView controller` in `attribute inspector` under `view Controller` tick `Adjust Scroll View Insets` or manually try  `yourTableViewName.contentInset =  UIEdgeInsets(top: 64, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)`

Comment: @Joe I added this `tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)` and I could see the tableView was further from the top, so it should work. But when I click one of the users and return to the search tableView - then it is behind the navigation bar again? Weird!

Comment: top: 20 only clears the statusBar not the NavigationBar (44) .You need to clear both 20+44 = 64

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931840/swift-uinavigationbar-only-sometimes-included-in-screen-height/39941844#39941844

Comment: @Joe by editing the 20 to 64 I am closer to the best result, than the answer from the other question - I have the same problem with the code from the other question, but when I add the 64 instead of 20 the tableview starts way too low beneath the navigationbar?? But when I click on a user (push to new VC) and then click back, then it is in the right place?? This is weird!

Comment: The cells from the UITableView only goes "under" the navigation bar, when I start typing in the search bar field, choose a user (pushed to new VC) and then return to search tableview...

Comment: Where you setting tableView content offset? .try setting up inside your 'numberOfRowsInSection' when searchBar active?

Comment: @Joe that did exactly the same as the other try :/

Comment: can you post a screenshot or screencast before & after searchBar active? and can you update your post with the current code.

Comment: try  `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != nil {

       searchUsersTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 64, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            return filteredUsers.count
        }

       searchUsersTableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        return usersArray.count
       }`

Comment: @Joe that did not work either. TableView only goes under nav bar when a cell has been clicked and the user returns to search bar tableview :(

Comment: can you post screenshot of your problem ?

Comment: @Joe added three screenshots :-)

Comment: can you take the `tableView insets off` and set your `tableViewCell height dynamically` this will  fix your screenshot 1 and 2 problem.let me know the o/p?

Comment: can you share your viewDidLoad if you running  any code related to searchController/tableView?