# UIView has top margin inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

I tried to put Container UIView inside UIScrollView as I saw many people recommended: put all margins of Container UIView and UIScrollView to 0 and add the constraints "Equal Height" and "Equal Width" to Container UIView in relation to the Main UIView, but the problem is that my Container UIView has top margin, I would say 64. This could be because of UINavigationController.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: please put the screenshot of your constraints.

Comment: refer to my previous ans may solves your prob http://stackoverflow.com/a/39590959/4003548.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by unchecking the property `Adjust Scroll View Insets` inside `attribute inspector` as [vaibhav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003548/vaibhav) answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39590834/i-want-to-place-table-view-exact-down-to-navigation-bar/39590959#39590959) question.